# javascript pass the into object method

Tags: javascript

I am calling a method and want to reference a object sprite outside the method with **this**.

Calling **this** in object only gives the passed in event object. I am trying to access this.sprite in the moveSprite:function

```
var roomMap = cc.Layer.extend({
    sprite:null,
    listener:null,

    ctor:function(){
        this._super();
        this.init();
    },

    init: function () {
        this._super();

        this.sprite = new cc.Sprite.create("#player-stand-f-0");
        this.sprite.setPosition(new cc.Point(300,300));
        this.addChild(this.sprite);

        this.listener = cc.EventListener.create({

            onMouseDown: function(event) {
                cc.log("onMouseDown");
            },
            onMouseUp: this.moveSprite
        });

        cc.eventManager.addListener(this.listener, this);

        return this;

    },

    moveSprite:function(event){
        cc.log("mouse up: "+event.getLocationX() + "mouse move: "+event.getLocationY());
        console.log(this);
        var sprite_action = cc.MoveTo(2,cc.p(event.getLocationX(),event.getLocationY()));
        this.sprite.runAction(sprite_action);
        this.addChild(sprite_action);
    }
```

});

Comment: You should explain what the library you're using is. Where's the documentation?

Comment: @JuanMendes: Such as it is: http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/v3/eventManager/en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your `cc` library gives you a specific way to do it, the *general* way to do it is with ES5's `Function#bind` (which can be shimmed on older engines):

```
onMouseUp: this.moveSprite.bind(this)
```

`Function#bind` returns a function that, when called, will call the original function with `this` set to the first argument you give `bind`. (You can also give `bind` further arguments, which will be passed to the original function as its initial arguments, followed by any that are given when calling the "bound" function that `bind` returns.)

So with the line above, we're saying "Create and return a function that, when called, will call `moveSprite` with `this` set to what `this` currently is, and assign that to the `onMouseUp` property."

Comment: Doesn't `cc.eventManager.addListener` look like it's setting `this`?

Comment: @JuanMendes: Well, the OP suggested that wasn't happening, so... But I agree, just looking at it, that's how I'd read that line, yeah. Would be really good to know what the `cc` lib was.

Comment: the cc lib is cocos2d-js

Comment: @JuanMendes: Oddly, it would appear that `addListener` *doesn't* use that second param for that (but I agree that that's what it looked like): *"You can add listener to `cc.eventManager` through `addListener`, `addListener` supports two parameters: `listener` and `nodeOrPriority`, if `nodeOrPriority` is a `cc.Node` or `cc.Node`'s subclass object, it will add listener as `SceneGraphPriority`, and if `nodeOrPriority` is number value, it will add listener as `FixedPriority`."*